# Sql query return nothing in the second time of executing (SQlite database)

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, sqlite

i have a problem with sqlite data base , i want that every moment that i type a character in an editable JcomboBox i get the data from sqlite database and add it as items to JComboBox after removing all existing  items .(i intend to create Autocompleting JComboBox ) 
this is the jComboBox code:

```
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
con = new Connect();

jComboBox1.setEditable(true);
for(String items :con.SelectDataforComboBox(
        "SELECT Reference FROM Articles",
        "SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTER FROM Articles","") ){
jComboBox1.addItem(items);}
con.CloseDB();
jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(
new KeyAdapter(){
   public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
con = new Connect();
char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        s = s+ c;
        System.out.println(s);   

jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
for(String items :con.SelectDataforComboBox(
        "SELECT Reference FROM Articles",
        "SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTER FROM Articles",s) ){
jComboBox1.addItem(items);}
con.CloseDB();

}}
);
```

and this the method returning items from database :

```
   public String [] SelectDataforComboBox(String sqlSelectlist , String sqlCount,String likeText){
       int k=0;
        try {       
            if(!likeText.equals("")){
                sqlCount = sqlCount + " WHERE Reference LIKE '"+likeText+"%'";
                sqlSelectlist = sqlSelectlist + " WHERE Reference LIKE '"+likeText+"%'";

            }
                System.out.println(sqlCount);
                System.out.println(sqlSelectlist);
            RsComboList = stmt.executeQuery(sqlCount);

                    while(RsComboList.next()){ 
                        ListofComboBox = new String[RsComboList.getInt("COUNTER")];
                        System.out.println(RsComboList.getInt("COUNTER"));
               }   

                                RsComboList = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelectlist);
            while(RsComboList.next()){

                        ListofComboBox[k]=RsComboList.getString("Reference");
                        System.out.print("Combobox : "+ListofComboBox[k]+"\n");
                        k++;

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }         


        return ListofComboBox ;
   }
```

So the problem is , when i type the first character i get the items , and when i add the second character the items removed and nothing returned from database and the jCombobox still empty , but when i execute the query in SQL Command (using Navicat) i get the data as usually  .What the solution?

**Edited**

```
This is the output of the query statement :

Opened database successfully
Records created successfully
m
SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTER FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE 'm%'
SELECT Reference FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE 'm%'
1
Combobox : Mehdi
DB closed
Opened database successfully
Records created successfully

SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTER FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE '%'
SELECT Reference FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE '%'
0
DB closed
Opened database successfully
Records created successfully
t
SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTER FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE 't%'
SELECT Reference FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE 't%'
0
DB closed
Opened database successfully
Records created successfully
tm
SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNTER FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE 'tm%'
SELECT Reference FROM Articles WHERE Reference LIKE 'tm%'
0
DB closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you may retrieve the full range of datas into a sorted list (cached in memory), then you can put only those items in combobox list, thats first x letters are equals to the entered text. On the beginning all items can be added. By this way you can reduce the I/O on database and it is faster to update the list of combobox...
Your combobox can be a general combobox with an internal protected sorted list for cache the full range of retireved data, that can be prepared (populated) with an external object (in this case a database handler object, that manages your SQLite access), that implements for example a `populateComboBox(YourComboBoxClass cb, String sql)` method...
The populateComboBox() can add retrieved data to the cached list of your combobox for example by calling your implemented `addCachedItem(String item)` function of your combobox...

By this way it will be most flexible and reusable, also you can populate the combobox by other datasources... may be you can add datas from more than one datasources if you dont clead th items...

Comment: tnx @Frakas Csaba , your solution is logic but i can't understand why queries return data in the first time i typed a character than in the next time whatever what i type the result is empty

Comment: After you entered the 2nd or 3rd characters, will the SQL select be correct? Is there any other event linked to the combobox, that uses the same database connection handler?

Comment: In the 2nd or 3rd time i type the character the query is correct but didn't return a result , there isn't another event , just the above event . and if  there is a problem in connection handler an exception will be appearing :) ....  so i can't see where is the problem